# How to test response with error in Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

This is part of the code I want to test:

```
 ngOnChanges() {
  this.searchCriteria$ = this.bookingService.getSearchCriteria(this.booking.id).pipe(
  catchError((err) => {
    this.error$ = of(err);

    return EMPTY;
   })
  );
 }
```

Below is my test case that fails with the Error:
***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')***

```
fit('should set error loading search criteria failed', () => {
  const errorMessage = 'Error getting search criteria';
  bookingService.getSearchCriteria.and.returnValue(throwError(() => new 
   Error(errorMessage)));

  component.ngOnChanges();

  component.error$.subscribe((error) => {
    expect(error).toBe(errorMessage);
  });
});
```

The thing that I also don't understand is when I *console.log* this:

```
fit('should set error loading search criteria failed', () => {
  const errorMessage = 'Error getting search criteria';
  bookingService.getSearchCriteria.and.returnValue(throwError(() => new 
  Error(errorMessage)));

  component.ngOnChanges();

  console.log(component.searchCriteria$.subscribe(() => {}));

  component.error$.subscribe((error) => {
    expect(error).toBe(errorMessage);
  });
});
```

I get a different Error: ***Expected Error: Error getting search criteria to be 'Error getting search criteria'.***

I don't know why this test fails, when the one before very similar succeeds:

```
  it('should load search criteria', () => {
   const searchCriteria = dataStore.deserializeModel(SearchCriteria, 
   searchCriteriaMock['data']);
   bookingService.getSearchCriteria.and.returnValue(of(searchCriteria));

   component.ngOnChanges();
   component.searchCriteria$.subscribe((criteria) => {
     expect(criteria).toEqual(searchCriteria);
   });
 });
```

One more confusing thing. When I use throwError(errorMessage) and have this `console.log(...)` the test is green... This cannot look like this since throwing the error like this is deprecated and `console.log()` needs to be gone:

```
  fit('should set error loading search criteria failed', () => {
   const errorMessage = 'Error getting search criteria';
   bookingService.getSearchCriteria.and.returnValue(throwError(errorMessage));
   component.ngOnChanges();

   console.log(component.searchCriteria$.subscribe(() => {}));

   component.error$.subscribe((error) => {
     expect(error).toBe(errorMessage);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an issue with how you're setting up your spies and handling asynchronous code in your Jasmine test. Also, note that using `throwError(errorMessage)` directly might not be the correct way. Instead, you should use `throwError(new Error(errorMessage))`.

In addition, you could (and probably should) mock your service and test the endpoints with simulated responses with `.callFake(of({ whatever you want to see in your test as response }))`.

Hope this helps.